# Oracle Apex tabs(Legacy) alternative in current apex version

Tags: oracle-apex

I am creating a project in Oracle Apex and need to create tabs in it like Employee Services, Manager Services etc.
However as per Apex documentation and what i read the option for creating tabs should be in Shared Components -> Navigation=> Tabs(Legacy). I found this option while importing an old apex project.

I need to implement similar thing using tabs in my latest apex application.
But what i see currently in Navigation menu  is -> Navigation Menu option instead of tabs.
They dont look the same.

Please advice on how to create tabs in Apex application.

Comment: One more thing, i can see Universal theme applied in shared componenets.  In navigation list-> i find navigation bar list option selected. Does it make any differnece?

Comment: Tabs for navigation is somewhat out-of-date. It was never a good analogy and it doesn't scale well on different devices. The newer menu options are better for navigation all around. Having said that, tabs can still be useful to sub-divide content on a given page and that can still be done very easily with APEX.

Answer (score 0):

You can create region on page, Type: Static Content; Appearance -> Template -> Tabs Container. All Sub-regions will be displayed as tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The Universal Theme uses navigation menus instead of legacy tabs, but these can still look like tabs.  See the [Universal Theme guide](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/navigation).

[image]